# chars that can never be typed by keyboard in java

Tags: java, string

Currently I am using java to create an app and in that app i am trying to add a code that manually serializes a class to a string and save it into a file

For example there is this class

```
public class dog{
    int age;
    int type; 
    String name;
}
```

And I chose to manually make this class into a string using this function, results in something that resembles an xml but just something that i made up.

```
public String classToString(dog d){
    String resultString = "" ;
    resultString + "#" ; 
    resultString + d.age;
    resultString + "#" ; 
    resultString + d.type;
    resultString + "#" ; 
    resultString + d.name;
    resultString + "#" ; 
    return resultString;

}
```

sp this function will return some sort of a string like

```
#7#4#Rex#
```

then when i read the file i will distinguish the different data by using # as some sort of a marking that separates different data,

what i am wondering is this,

1. Is this a good practice? I don't need to conceal the data from people who will open the file directly from a text viewer, so I think this would be okay. But is it efficient? are there better ways?
2. The biggest problem I am facing is that what if a the string that should be stored includes the special character that I have chosen which is ('#')?

   To solve this problem I am wondering if there is a special preserved character that can't be written with keyboards or other user interfaces so I'd never have to save a string that includes that character
3. I am also thinking of making every 5th character empty so then I only write data on 4 spaces and make every 5th space empty so I can use it for special markings. for example if the age is 7 and type is 10 and the name of the dog is "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" the result string would be

   ## #0007#0010#abcd^efgh^ijkl^.........^yz  <

'#' is a data separator

^ is just a character that means data shouldn't be separated at this point

< means that if there are blank space characters on the left of this marking, they shouldn't be considered as part of the data and should be cut off

Comment: The usual way is to have some kind of escape for the separator like backslash for the `"` in java strings

Comment: Couldn't you create an interface called `Stateful` with `load()` and `save ()` methods. Your `Dog` class can implement it and those methods will be responsible for loading and saving based off of the data coming and going?

Comment: If you want to store it in human readable format, why not using a format for which already library exists: json, xml, cvs, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface called `Stateful`, for example. Any class implementing this interface will be responsible for loading and saving.

#### DogTest.java

```
public class DogTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dogA = new Dog(7, 10, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

        String state = dogA.save();
        System.out.println(state); // #0007#0010#abcd^efgh^ijkl^mnop^qrst^uvwx^yz#

        Dog dogB = new Dog().load(state);
        System.out.println(dogB); // Dog [age=7, type=10, name=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]
    }
}
```

#### Stateful.java

```
public interface Stateful<T> {
    static final String DATA_SEP = "#";
    static final String SEGMENT_SEP = "^";

    T load(String data);
    String save();
}
```

#### Dog.java

```
public class Dog implements Stateful<Dog> {
    private int age;
    private int type;
    private String name;

    public Dog() {
        this(0, 0, "");
    }

    public Dog(int age, int type, String name) {
        super();
        this.age = age;
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dog [age=" + age + ", type=" + type + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public Dog load(String data) {
        String[] fragments = StatefulUtil.parse(data);

        this.age = Integer.parseInt(fragments[1], 10);
        this.type = Integer.parseInt(fragments[2], 10);
        this.name = StatefulUtil.decode(fragments[3]);

        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String save() {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(Stateful.DATA_SEP);

        buff.append(StatefulUtil.format(this.age)).append(Stateful.DATA_SEP);
        buff.append(StatefulUtil.format(this.type)).append(Stateful.DATA_SEP);
        buff.append(StatefulUtil.encode(this.name)).append(Stateful.DATA_SEP);

        return buff.toString();
    }
}
```

#### StatefulUtil.java

```
public class StatefulUtil {
    public static CharSequence encode(String value) {
        return separate(escape(value), Stateful.SEGMENT_SEP, 4);
    }

    public static String decode(String value) {
        return join(value.split("\\" + Stateful.SEGMENT_SEP), "").toString();
    }

    private static String escape(String value) {
        return value.replace(Stateful.DATA_SEP, "\\" + Stateful.DATA_SEP);
    }

    public static CharSequence format(int value) {
        return String.format("%04d", value);
    }

    public static CharSequence separate(String value, String separator, int offset) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(value);
        int n = buff.length() / offset;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int index = i + ((i + 1) * offset);
            buff.insert(index, separator);
        }

        return buff;
    }

    public static CharSequence join(String[] arr, String separator) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

        if (arr != null) {
            if (arr.length > 0) {
                buff.append(arr[0]);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                buff.append(separator).append(arr[i]);
            }
        }

        return buff;
    }

    // Regular expression: /^#|[^\\\\]#/ - Match beginning '#' and each non-escaped '#"
    public static String[] parse(String data) {
        return data.split("^" + Stateful.DATA_SEP + "|[^\\\\]" + Stateful.DATA_SEP);
    }
}
```

Comment: But your solution still doesn't handle point two from the question: `The biggest problem I am facing is that what if a the string that should be stored includes the special character that I have chosen which is ('#')?`

Comment: @SubOptimal Actually the above code does work, since separators only occur in every 5 spaces it is easy to tell if it is a # that is included in the data or a # that is a data separator. Thanks to both of you anyway. :-)

Comment: @NamHoLee Maybe I did not understand your intention. But `Dog dogA = new Dog(7, 10, "a#bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")` results in `Dog [age=7, type=10, name=a]`.

Comment: @SubOptimal: I added a parse method in the utility class to check for escaped `#`s. A valid string would be `"a\\#bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` The string is not escaped and parsed with the escape in-mind.

Comment: oh now I see what @SubOptimal meant.. I didn't actually read through the whole code when I posted that Comment , my bad  .

Comment: @NamHoLee: Well, I added escaping. If the user tries to deserialize an unescaped Dog name, then that is a user error, because the name now gets escaped when it is serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `Stateful` or a `Serializable` class. Here's an example of a serializable class:

```
public class Dog implements Serializable {
 ...
 }
```

Then you can use an `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` to write and read the object respectively.

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream( yourFileStream );
out.writeObject(yourDogObject);
```

That will write the `yourDogObject` out to `yourFileStream`.

Answer (score 0):

As such an application may grow, and data change, my preference would be for XML, using JAXB with annotations. At least some human readable text, maybe versioned.

```
Dog dog = load(Dog.class, "dog.xml");
```

The loading/saving code is something like:

```
public <T> T load(Class<T> type, String path) {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance();
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    return type.cast(u.unmarshal(new FileInputStream(path));
}

public <T> void save(T obj, String path) {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance();
    Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
    m.unmarshal(obj, new FileOutputStream(path));
}
```

And with annotations you may control the XML:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="dog")
public class Dog implements Stateful<Dog> {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "vs")
    private String dataVersion = "1.0";

    @XmlAttribute(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @XmlAttribute
    private int type;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

for

```
<dog vs="1.0" age="6" type="3">
    <name>Cerberus</name>
</dog>
```

One can have lists etcetera.